# angular.toJson/JSON.stringify values incorrect?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object attached to a `$scope` that I want to serialize into JSON. The object has been setup with data binding so there are input fields using `ng-model` and what not. When attempting to call `angular.toJson`, the values aren't up to date.

The strange thing is that I figured my values weren't being updated like I thought. So I threw in some `console.log` calls for simplicity yet the values from `console.log` are correct yet they aren't for the JSON conversion? I tested it with `JSON.stringify` as well but the results were the same. Code:

```
// This looks fine
console.log('Data:', $scope.obj);
var temp = angular.toJson($scope.obj);
// This looks fine as well...
console.log('Data:', $scope.obj);
// Yet the JSON string isn't correct and contains old data?
console.log('Data:', temp);
```

Is this an Angular issue that I'm over looking that has to do with data binding? Or is something else going on?

Comment: What do you mean values are not up to date? could you post more code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling var `temp = angular.toJson($scope.obj);` directly before working with `temp` variable for example by clicking the special button or doing like this:

```
var temp;
$scope.$watch('obj', function(newVal) {
    temp = angular.toJson(newVal);
    console.log('Data:', temp);
});
```

Please keep in mind that `console.log()` can print object not in that state when `console.log()` called. `console.log()` prints actual state only for string/number/boolean values. But if you called `console.log($scope.obj)` and after that `$scope.obj` is changed somewhere in the code (by loading the info via ajax, by event or by `$scope.$apply()`) you will see changed object in console (this works for DOM objects a well).

Comment: Interesting. I did not know that about `console.log` that is definitely what is going on then. I'm modifying the value in a directive so it must not just be propagating up yet. Thanks for the pointers and info!